# PHP objective sometimes work sometimes not

Tags: php, logic

I'm facing a really weird problem on php 5.3.28

i have this code :

```
ob_start( );
session_start( );
include( "../common.php" );
check_user_login( );
$Pageination->Pagination( );
$p = $Pageination;
```

i use this code for all my website for pagination, but i dont know why some time i get this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Pagination() in

and sometime this code **work just fine** with out error !

**[UPDATED 1 ]**

this code from my main/main.php

```
ob_start( );
session_start( );
include( "../common.php" );
check_user_login( );
$Var_120->Pagination( );
$p = $Var_120;
$page = setpage( );
$Var_336->AdminLoginlist( );
$al = $Var_336;
```

and its working

no this code from my main/edit-faq.php

```
ob_start( );
session_start( );
include( "../common.php" );
check_user_login( );
$Var_312->Pagination( );
$p = $Var_312;
$page = setpage( );
$Var_528->viewcategory( );
```

not working and error is right at

> Fatal error: Call to a member function Pagination() on a non-object
>   in /home/zmiintco/public_html/z/main/edit-faq.php on line 91

this is my common.php code

```
include( "lib/connect.php" );
include( "lib/function.php" );
include( "lib/pagination.php" );
include( "lib/validation.php" );
include( "lib/simpleimage.php" );
include( "language/".get_page_settings( "11" ).".php" );
```

Comment: Doesn't it bother you that 'Pagination' is spelled two different ways within the same line of code?

Comment: I never thought/ about it ,

Answer (score 0):

You probably have error reporting set to not display warnings. As a result you don't see that your `include()` statement fails. As a result your Paginator class is not available to your script and causes a fatal error when you try to instantiate it.

See [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) for details on how to set up error reporting properly.

This is most likely due to the fact that you use a relative path to that file which is incorrect when the script is not one directory beneath the directory containing it. Change the path to the include to be an absolute path to solve this problem.

For example:

```
include( "/full/path/to/includes/common.php" );
```

Comment: im perty sure i dont have any related path problem

Comment: "Pretty sure" is not "100% sure". And it is the *only* explanation for why it sometimes works. It is generally a good practice to use full paths to avoid this issue anyway.

Comment: both of them use same code one working another dont .

Comment: That's a good indication that this is your problem. Have you tried putting **the full path in your PHP code**? That is how you will know for sure. It should be **the very next thing you do**.

Comment: is it possible my shared host is source of all my problem ?

Comment: It is very unlikely. There isn't raelly anything they can do to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set your error reporting on at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Now you will most likely get the error (*as you stated*) that:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function Pagination() in

And that would be because your variable `$Pageination` wasn't instantiated.
Simply instantiate it and then call its member functions.

```
ob_start( );
session_start( );
include( "../common.php" );
check_user_login( );

$Pageination = new Pagination();
$Pageination->Pagination( );
$p = $Pageination;
```

Pressuming that it is a class that is present somewhere within your `common.php` include?

---

Could you possibly show the code within your `common.php` ?

Comment: @madman Where are you instantiating the these classes to be able to call its methods?

Comment: here is my my pagination class Pagination{function getPaginationString... but i cant understand your question

Comment: @madman My question is: Where are you creating these classes? i.e. - `$pageination = new Pagination();`?

Comment: in line 90 right after class finished like this <?php class foo { bar { }} $pageination = new Pagination(); ... ?>

Comment: @madman Is all spelling/variable names correct? It is case-sensitive..?

Comment: is it good idea start obj and session in line 90 i think this is my problem